# In Android---How to check TextToSpeech Text capacity(Queue capacity)?

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

Any one know the capacity of TextToSpeech Text Reading Capacity at one Time?

Means how many kilobyte file Speak at Time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code shows you the maximum number of characters:

```
int num = android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.getMaxSpeechInputLength(); // num = 4000 characters string maximum
```